# How to reload texture images when they've changed on disk

Tags: texturing

I'm texturing in Substance Painter, and exporting the resulting textures to a sub-directory under my blender file. I'm then assigning it by choosing "Image Texture", and then "Open" to select the file on disk.

[image]

However, if I go back to Substance Painter and export the textures again (overwriting the old textures, but keeping the same names), blender doesn't update to show the new textures.

I'm hoping there's a some way to get all of the materials to "refresh" and show the latest version of the texture. Have I not linked the texture properly? Do I need to do something special to force all textures to refresh?

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in the *Image Editor* or in the *UV Editor > Image > Reload* (or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you use the addon [Amaranth Toolset](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/interface/amaranth.html#save-reload-file) provided with Blender, you can use "*Save & Reload File*" in the File menu or via <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>.

Otherwise, you can do the same manually by saving and then using the menu File > Reload.

"Reload" essentially refreshes the file's data as if you opened it again (hence the need to save you did anything you want to keep).

If you have multiple textures (or any other kind of data) to refresh, that's the one click solution.